# Include the same forms twice in other one - Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

I want to do something with Symfony but it seems to be complicate : I want to include the same form twice in other one. I explain: I have two entities named `Evenement` and `TypeEvenement` and on my form I want that the user select a `TypeEvenement` when he creates an `Evenement` or he can add a `TypeEvenement`.

Technically, it give this :

```
-> add ('typeEvenenement', 'entity', array(
'class'  => 'FFESponsorBundle:TypeEvenement',
'property' => 'nom',
'multiple' => true,
))

->add ('typeEvenement', 'collection', array(
'type' => new TypeEvenementType(),
'allow_add' => true,
'allow_delete' => true,
))
```

But there is a conflict. Indeed, the collection take the priority on the entity. I tried to modify my form like this :

```
-> add ('typeEven', 'entity', array(
'class'  => 'FFESponsorBundle:TypeEvenement',
'property' => 'nom',
'multiple' => true,
))
```

By define on my entity getters and setters for don't have error with the same values than `getTypeEvenement()`, etc ... 
But I have a gain a conflict. So I have tried to found on other solution : I have found the readonly property. By playing a bit with JQuery, I can put this property and in this case, I can create `TypeEvenement` object with the collection field. But when I want to do the opposite, the `TypeEvenement` selected is not joined to the `Evenement` created on the database.

I am a bit lost and I begin to think that's my problem is impossible.

Anyone has an idea about my 3 proposition or an other one to give to myself ?

Thanks guys

Comment: What relation have you set up between `Evenement` and `TypeEvenement` ? OneToMany or ManyToMany ?

Comment: I think you are true, fields name must be different , add a little script to toggle your form field but i think you must [dynamically modify your form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

Comment: @Tom Toms : I have a ManyToMany relation. Why ?

Comment: @Charlie Lucas : what type of modification correspond to my problem ?

Comment: No new idea for me ? :/

Comment: For me if you use 2 "type of form"(entity/collection) for your many to many, you must do a data-transformer like entityToCollection. But i prefer make 2 different mapping for you relation, a many to many(typeEvenement) and a many to one(TypeEven) and maybe add a method in your evenement entity "isCollectionEvenement" which return a boolean if typeEven is defined or not.